# Convert CSV to text and automatically remove quotes and a specific word - Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

I need to convert .csv to .txt format via CL (Command line) and automatically remove quotes and a specific word - Linux.

**Example:**
I have multiple exported csv files that have:

1. At first row I have: "Address" **- I want this row deleted**
2. Next rows have something like:

```
"https://www.example.com/21"
    
"https://www.example.com/22"
    
...
    
"https://www.example.com/99000"
```

**In point 2 I want the quotation marks removed.**

I have tried multiple sed and awk commands but they fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat filename.csv 
"Address"
"https://www.example.com/21"
"https://www.example.com/22"
...
"https://www.example.com/99000"
$ sed -n '2,$s/"//gp' filename.csv > filename.txt
$ cat filename.txt 
https://www.example.com/21
https://www.example.com/22
https://www.example.com/99000
```

If you want the `...` as well; just add a `;` between the g and p in `gp`

Comment: Perfectly! Thank you @tink

Comment: My pleasure .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed [-i[suffix]] 's/^[^,]*,"\([^",]*\)"/\1/' inputfile
```

Explanation (thank you @Hannu for suggestions):

- with `-i`, `sed` overwrites the input file with the output;
- with `-i.bak,` sed` also saves the unaltered input file, renaming it to inputfile.bak;
- `[^,]` (which means: everything except `,`) and `[^",]` (everything except `"` or `,`) are used because Kleene stars (`*`) are greedy: they will try to match as much as possible.

Comment: ... and the optional `-i` as indicated by [-i] is to do this "in place" in a file, the name of which has to be given as second argument (missing). Also add e.g. `-e '1d'` to delete the first line?

Comment: In my `sed` (Ubuntu's), the argument after `-i` is optional.

Comment: man sed => `-i[SUFFIX]` yes, but the presence of `-i` means that you're intending to do the operation on the content of a file; so which file do you work on?  *(Note `edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)` in the man page)*

Comment: `-i` means you edit the file in place.

Comment: @reinierpost - Doesn't work: 
1. zsh (My Shell): zsh: wrong model: [-i.  
2. Without [-i] - it remove quotes and filename.csv is not converted (output) to filename.txt. (first row "Address" is not removed)
.Can you please give an example using filename.csv?

Comment: @Marius: thanks, it's better now. I actually tested in this time.

Comment: @reinierpost - Does not work for me: zsh: no matches found: [-i[suffix]]. I have the CSV called: filename.csv > I want filename.txt. The filename.txt to have removed quotes inside and first row deleted.

Comment: If that's what you want, don't use `-i`. For your information, `sed` comes with a manual.